# SQL Server ContainsTable not returning result with term "inn"

Tags: sql-server, containstable

I have a table called `hotel` with the following information:

- `Hotel_Id`: 2950
- `Hotel_Name`: Inn on the Park
- `Hotel_Number`: 01234567
- `Hotel_TypeId`: 1

I need to be able to search for records where the name column contains certain terms.

The search is:

```
select * 
from ContainsTable(hotel, Hotel_Name, '"Inn on Park"')
```

I get no results but if I search:

```
select * 
from ContainsTable(hotel, Hotel_Name, '"In on Park"')
```

I get

```
Key: 2950
Rank: 176
```

I figured there was some issue with the term "inn" but if I search for:

```
select * 
from ContainsTable(hotel, Hotel_Name, '"Inn"')
```

I get back the same key: 2950, Rank: 176 result.

Is "inn" a keyword that is causing this problem?

Comment: This is a bug in a live DB with loads of rows but I've created a tmp table and only have the one row in it which is "Inn on the Park"

Comment: What does the following query return: `select display_term from sys.dm_fts_parser('"Inn on Park"', your_lcid, 0, 0)` (you can try *your_lcid* with both 0 and your actual locale identifier)?

Comment: For both 0 and 2057 (british english) lcid, I get back the same results... display_term: inn, on, park

Comment: Yeh, that was my bad - I was interested to know how your search would treat the `the` (if it was a _stop word/noise word_ or not), but forgot to add it in the query :) Anyway, since "In on Park" seemed to be working I guess I'm on the wrong track anyway. Perhaps redoing the fulltext index would help - not sure.

Comment: Well, if I add "the" into the query, it is returned in the result list. The application sitting on top of this query does strip out noise words like "the" and "on" anyway. My real confusion is just on the "inn" not working but "in". I have rebuilt the index but it has no effect, I've also tried changing the locale of the index, again no luck.

Comment: I've tried changing the hotel name to: "Inn onn the park". And if I search for "onn the park", I get no results but if I search for "on the park" i do. So I guess it's, if a noise/key word has the extra character it becomes a problem?

Comment: It really shouldn't. But when you say "*The application sitting on top of this query does strip out noise words*", do you mean sql server, or some other application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is my theory..

Your hotel name, `Inn on the Park`, would be index like this:

```
pos   word
1     Inn
2     (noise)
3     (noise)
4     Park
```

*on* and *the* are stop/noise words, and not stored in the index (but notice that the position is still stored).

You're searching by a full string. Taking in to account the noise words this would mean:

```
Query 1: "Inn on Park" -> "Inn (noise) Park"
Query 2: "In on Park" -> "(noise) (noise) Park"
```

Your indexed string (hotel name) is `Inn (noise) (noise) Park`, so this would be a partial match on the second query, but no match on the first.

This can be tested by for example searching for `Inn 1 1 Park`. This will return a result. But `Inn 1 Park` or `1 Inn 1 Park` will not (positions does not correspond).

To "fix" this you could use different operators, like AND, OR or NEAR:

```
"Inn" AND "Park"
"Inn*"
"Inn" NEAR "Park"
```

Here are two screenshots, showing the results of your main queries. Notice how the second will only search for "*Park*", or "*noise noise Park*" (any of those would return results):

[image]

[image]

Comment: OK, that makes sense. I didn't know the position of the noise word was important.

In the real life scenario, there on and the are stripped out before it goes into the query so this would explain it.

Is there anyway that this can be overcome or would I need to not strip out the noise words in the query?

Comment: @GPW I think it would be best to either separate each word between `AND`, like my example above, or send the whole search string to SQL and let it handle the _noises_. If you've already identified them in your front-end, you can just send any noise word (`a`) in the search term though.

Comment: Thanks so much @Mackan. That was starting to get the better of me. I will just stop stripping out the noise words.

Comment: Beware searching with AND.  If search text contains any noise-word, then containstable will return 0 results.  This is stupid.  You can re-configure SQL Server to change that behaviour.  e.g. `sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;  
RECONFIGURE;  
GO  
sp_configure 'transform noise words', 1;  
RECONFIGURE;  
GO ` See [link]https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187914.aspx

Comment: +1 Thanks this really helped me with [my issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48212372/sql-server-containstable-not-working-for-single-digit-numbers/48212373#48212373).